# Need help resolving a JavaScript conflict using jQuery Anything Slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

The site has an existing rotating header banner and I am attempting to add CSS-Trick's AnythingSlider to the body.

When the AnythingSlider is added, the rotating banner breaks.  Here is my test page http://www.visfire.com/slidertest.html.  Please see the home page to view the current rotating banner in action.  I have tried turning off different versions of the multiple jQuery libraries referenced in the head but have not had any success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually quite a simple solution. You have your `jquery.js` file (which is the header rotator code) before the actual jquery javascript file.

Currently you have this:

```
<script src="js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Swap those two and you get:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

That should do the trick.